# 403 Forbidden error for Wordpress login after whitelisting Cloudflare IPs in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, cloudflare, 403-forbidden

I’m using Cloudflare nameservers and tried to whitelist Cloudflare IPs through htaccess file, but it results in a 403 Forbidden error for my Wordpress login.

Here are the directives I used in htaccess file:

```
# Apache 2.2: Whitelist Cloudflare IPs
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 173.245.48.0/20
Allow from 103.21.244.0/22
Allow from 103.22.200.0/22
Allow from 103.31.4.0/22
Allow from 141.101.64.0/18
Allow from 108.162.192.0/18
Allow from 190.93.240.0/20
Allow from 188.114.96.0/20
Allow from 197.234.240.0/22
Allow from 198.41.128.0/17
Allow from 162.158.0.0/15
Allow from 104.16.0.0/12
Allow from 172.64.0.0/13
Allow from 131.0.72.0/22
</IfModule>
# Apache 2.4+: Whitelist Cloudflare IPs
<IfModule authz_core_module>
<RequireAll>
Require ip 173.245.48.0/20
Require ip 103.21.244.0/22
Require ip 103.22.200.0/22
Require ip 103.31.4.0/22
Require ip 141.101.64.0/18
Require ip 108.162.192.0/18
Require ip 190.93.240.0/20
Require ip 188.114.96.0/20
Require ip 197.234.240.0/22
Require ip 198.41.128.0/17
Require ip 162.158.0.0/15
Require ip 104.16.0.0/12
Require ip 172.64.0.0/13
Require ip 131.0.72.0/22
</RequireAll>
</IfModule>
```

This blocked me from login in Wordpress, so I tried to add this along with the above directives:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all granted
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
```

But this didn’t work!

What can I do, please, to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the `authz_core_module` altogether?   Usually once you have a CDN, there is no need for such a module on the origin server.

Comment: OK, @StephenOstermiller; I'll try to disable the `authz_core_module` and let you know of the result. As for the greetings and thanks, I'll try next time to be less polite as much as I can :-)

Answer (score 1):

> This blocked me from login in ...

I would have expected this to have blocked your entire site, not just the login?

> ```
> <RequireAll>
> Require ip 173.245.48.0/20
> Require ip 103.21.244.0/22
> Require ip 103.22.200.0/22
> Require ip 103.31.4.0/22
> :
> </RequireAll>
> ```

Only 1 IP will access at any one time, so most of these `Require ip` directives will *fail*, so the `<RequireAll>` directive will fail and access will be blocked.

It should be `<RequireAny>` instead. Or omitted altogether (since that is the default).

Comment: I will try to change the `<RequireAll>` to `<RequireAny>` and see what it does. I'll let you know for any result.

Comment: I used `<RequireAny>` but access to wp-admin was still forbidden. I deleted it, but same result. I tried to delete all the block related to Apache 2.2, but same result. Then, I deleted the block related to Apache 2.4, and it worked! But, my server information in  cPanel indicates that it has Apache 2.4+; so I'm not sure if I should keep only the Apache 2.2 directives!!... Should I check with the hosting provider!!?

Comment: "I deleted the block related to Apache 2.4, and it worked!" - Doesn't that indicate that your server IS Apache 2.4? Is it _only_ the wp_admin section that is blocked; not the entire site? If so, then that would seem to indicate _something else_ is blocking you? (Unless you are only putting these directives in the wp_admin subdirectory?!) Check your server's access log and the IP address that is being blocked - is this included in the stated IP ranges? (The Apache 2.2 block won't do anything on Apache 2.4 because the directives are in an `<IfModule !authz_core_module>` container.)

Comment: - Yes; I can confirm from cPanel that the server is Apache 2.4.
- wp-admin section is the only one that is blocked when using the above whitelisting Cloudflare IPs method.
- The htaccess file used is the one at the root of the domain (not just in the wp-admin subdirectory).